# importing TypeScript vs ES2015

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to figure out why TypeScript is not picking up the `"default export"` of `react`. E.g. in my JavScript files I was using:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

But in typescript I have to use (after some googling):

```
import * as React from "react"
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom"
```

I am just starting out with a fresh project after being unable to import my existing project and g et VS2k15 to compile it.

What is the difference, if any? Is there a way to specify a `"Module 'react' has no default export"`.

I can see in the React file there is

```
declare module "react" {
    export = __React;
}
```

Is that not considered a `default export`

I also tried

```
import __React from "react"
```

but get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

A default export is just giving one of the exports the alias "default". You can do this using the following syntax:

```
export default function __React {
    //do work
}
```

You can also use the following syntax:

```
function __React {
    //do work
}

export {__React as default};
```